# How can I use the SendGrid Parse API and Google Apps at the same time?

Tags: email, dns, google-apps, sendgrid

I'm using the [SendGrid Parse API](http://sendgrid.com/documentation/display/api/Parse) to accept emails from users at ANYTHING@example.com, but I want to also be able to receive emails to Google Apps at support@example.com. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible but you have a few options. You could have some code in your parse API callback that forwards emails that match certain rules to a different address (you'd have to rebuild the messages from the parsed values), or you could add a subdomain with a different MX record and use that for either support or parsing but not both.

Comment: Just curious, which one would you use for parsing and which one for support?

Comment: I would probably use a subdomain for everything to be parsed, just to make it less likely for messages that aren't intended to be parsed to be accidentally sent to that domain